# How to change key names in laravel collection?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, orm

I'm working with a model instance that includes many-to-many relationship data. While everything is in good condition, I'm facing an issue with the keys' names. I aim to send a JSON response with better camelCase keys, but I'm struggling to make the necessary changes.

Here's a snippet of the collection object when converted to an array:

```
array:28 [
  "id" => 268897045
  "name" => "remitterNew22June"
  "name_last" => "singh"
  // ... (other keys)
  "beneficiaries" => array:2 [
    0 => array:28 [
      "id" => 11969779
      "account" => "ATROUNTNUMBEE"
      "name" => "firstName lastName"
      // ... (other keys)
    ]
    1 => array:28 [
      "id" => 11969780
      "account" => "ATROUNTNUMBEE"
      "name" => "firstName lastName"
      // ... (other keys)
    ]
  ]
]
```

The challenge arises when converting this collection to an array, as all the keys are in snake_case. My main focus is to change these keys, for example, renaming name_last in the outer array to lastName.

I'm aware of the option to use SQL aliases or query builders, but I want to avoid altering the collection directly.

One method I've considered involves using the map function to modify the keys, as shown below:

```
$remitterDetails->beneficiaries = $remitterDetails->beneficiaries->map(function ($beneficiary) {
    return [
        'account' => $beneficiary->account,
        'name' => $beneficiary->name,
        'gender' => $beneficiary->gender,
        'beneficiaryId' => $beneficiary->bene_id,
    ];
});
```

In summary, I have a model instance with many-to-many relationship data, and I want to return this data in a modified form with camelCase keys for both the outer and inner arrays.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're on the right track with using the map function to transform the keys. You can extend this approach to handle both the outer and inner arrays. Here's an example:

```
$remitterDetailsArray = [
        "id" => 268897045,
        "name" => "remitterNew22June",
        "name_last" => "singh",
        // ... (other keys)
        "beneficiaries" => [
            [
                "id" => 11969779,
                "account" => "ATROUNTNUMBEE",
                "name" => "firstName lastName",
                // ... (other keys)
            ],
            [
                "id" => 11969780,
                "account" => "ATROUNTNUMBEE",
                "name" => "firstName lastName",
                // ... (other keys)
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $remitterDetailsArray = array_map(function ($key) {
        // Convert snake_case to camelCase
        return lcfirst(str_replace('_', '', ucwords($key, '_')));
    }, array_keys($remitterDetailsArray));

    $remitterDetailsArray = array_combine($remitterDetailsArray, array_values($remitterDetailsArray));

    $remitterDetailsArray['beneficiaries'] = array_map(function ($beneficiary) {
        return array_map(function ($key) {
            // Convert snake_case to camelCase for inner array keys
            return lcfirst(str_replace('_', '', ucwords($key, '_')));
        }, array_keys($beneficiary));
    }, $remitterDetailsArray['beneficiaries']);
```